# How to update only the currently selected ng-repeat element instead of all

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having the following problem: 
I have written an app where one can repeatedly add a div that contains two select boxes. The contents of the second select box depend on the selection of the first select box. However, once I select a specific item from the first select box, the contents of all existing second select boxes are updated. What I want is only the current second select box to be updated.

Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fdDKRjO69GA3eTA4NH7S?p=preview)

Whenever I have 1..n select boxes already and then select ***specialItem4*** from the first select box of the current div, all preceding second select boxes are updated as well and contain just the two selection options ***special1*** and ***special2*** which are defined for ***specialItem4*** only. I just want that current second select box to be updated:

A snippet of the HTML code:

```
<div ng-switch-default="ng-switch-default">
      <select ng-model="rule.parameter" ng-options="sel1.name for sel1 in selects1" ng-change="change(rule.parameter)"></select>
      <select ng-options="sel2 for sel2 in filteredselect2" ng-model="rule.relation"></select>
</div>
```

A snipped of the JS code:

```
    scope.change = function (sel2Selection) {
        scope.filteredselect2 = [];
        for(var key in scope.selects2){
            if(angular.isDefined(scope.selects2[key][sel2Selection.relation])){
                scope.filteredselect2 = scope.selects2[key][sel2Selection.relation];
            }
        }
    };
```

I'd be grateful for help as I am a total newbie to AngularJS.

Comment: It looks like your directive has the repeat in it so the scope used in each of your select boxes is the same one.  You probably want to have a directive for each pair of select boxes so that the scope.filteredselect2 variable contains a different array for each pair.

Comment: Could you give me an example maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the list to use as the second dropdown varies in each pair, it needs to be isolated. Using a directive for the pair of dropdowns would allow you to encapsulate all the logic related to the two dropdowns together. In your case move the change listener into the new directive like so:

```
dynamicSelect.directive('dynamicSelectPair', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      rule: '=',
      selects1: '=',
      selects2: '='
    },
    template: '<select ng-model="rule.parameter" ng-options="sel1.name for sel1 in selects1" ng-change="change(rule.parameter)"></select><select ng-options="sel2 for sel2 in filteredselect2" ng-model="rule.relation"></select>',
    link: function(scope) {
      // change the second select content depending on the select item of the first select
        scope.change = function(sel2Selection) {
          scope.filteredselect2 = [];

          for (var key in scope.selects2) { 
            if (angular.isDefined(scope.selects2[key][sel2Selection.relation])) {
              scope.filteredselect2 = scope.selects2[key][sel2Selection.relation];
            }
          }
        };
    }
  }  
});
```

Then change your HTML to use the new directive in your ng-repeat. Note that, the possible values for the selects can be passed down into the directive since you already have them in the outer scope.

```
 <div ng-switch-default="ng-switch-default">
        <div dynamic-select-pair selects1='selects1' selects2='selects2' rule='rule'>
 </div>
```

Here is an updated Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Sr1s6I3zleCGr95eYa9e?p=preview

Comment: Hi thanx alot! This is what I was looking for. One more question tho: is it possible for the dropdowns to remain in my html file? The project is much bigger with more html elements inside a form and I'd like to keep everything in one place.

Comment: The "Angular way" would typically be to put the template it its own file and then reference the file using the "templateUrl" property of the directive definition object instead inlining the html "template" property. I updated the plunker to show that.

Comment: Thanx again @mcgraphix. What I meant specifically is that I have other html elements that are altered in the other directive through function calls made in the new directive. For instance, when the drop down boxes in directive "dynamicSelectPair" are clicked, a function "checkComplete()" is supposed to be called which is implemented in the directive "dynamicSelect" and turns on another button: `<select ng-model="rule.parameter" ng-options="sel1.name for sel1 in selects1" ng-change="change(rule.parameter)" ng-click="checkComplete()">`.

Comment: `checkComplete()` is implemented in directive `dynamicSelect`. I have read about using `require` and controllers for communication between directives but I think this is not possible in my case because I am using a `compile` in the `dynamicSelect` directive. Here is a [Plunker](http://http://plnkr.co/edit/oYIUFFUEaA2SOmGQbvQY?p=preview) with the example (not working).

Comment: You can pass in that function as an event handler: scope: { rule: '=', selects1: '=', selects2: '=' , change: "&"} then add change="change" on your html tag

Comment: So, _change_ is referring to the name of my function? What does the _&_ mean? What I want is `checkComplete()` being called from the `ng-click` event. So, all I have to do is `scope: { rule: '=', selects1: '=', selects2: '=' , checkComplete: '&'}` and in my html tag adding `checkComplete='checkComplete'`? Is there a reason why you wrote the _&_ and the _change_ in double  quotes instead of single?

Comment: The "&" means that what you are passing in is a function which will be available on your directive's scope as scope.change(). So in your case if you want to call it checkComplete, that's fine but when you put in your html it would have to be check-complete="checkComplete()". I have seen people spend hours trying to figure out why checkComplete="checkComplete()" doesn't work. So remember that in your directive definition, you use camel case but as an html attribute you have to use snake case. Not reason for the double quotes. I was typing that on my phone :-)